# VirtualBox on Fedora 24 question

Tags: virtualbox

What does it mean to have a Saved State, as it relates to a Guest Virtual Machine OS?  As well what is the relationship between the Saved State and Snapshots?

Answer (score 2):

Saved state can be best described or compared to hibernate. It basically hibernates the Virtual Machine and saves the state of all running programs and processes in memory so that you can resume it exactly where it left off without having to boot it back up from scratch.

A snapshot is more related to the state of the filesystem and all configuration files of the operating system and installed applications. So you can take a snapshot before you go experimentally installing or un-installing something so that incase it messes up the system you can just simply revert to your snapshot and it would be as though nothing ever happened.

Comment: When I attempt to discard a saved state it says "Are you sure you want to discard the saved state of the following virtual machines?
WIN2KK
This operation is equivalent to resetting or powering off the machine without doing a proper shutdown of the guest OS."  What am I to think of this comment?  Will it actually "destabilize" the OS within my VirtualBox/VM environment?

Comment: it will be equivalent to pulling the power plug on a running machine. Are you trying to shutdown or power off the Virtual Machine ? Or is it giving errors to start because of the saved state being invalid or corrupt ? Either way if the saved state file is causing you problems, it is ok to discard it. Windows wouldn't like it very much but it will survive just fine.